# Unable to add a reference to project - UWP to Class Library project?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, visual-studio-project

A WPF project and a UWP project share the same solution. Can both projects reference a common project?

- "Common" - .NET 6 target framework, class library
- "UWP" - targets Windows 10 Creators Update (Build 15063)
- "WPF App" - .NET 6 target framework, references "WPF2"
- "WPF2" - .NET 6 target framework

The "WPF" project can reference "Common" no problem, but the "UWP" project says "Unable to add a reference to project 'Common'".

[image: unable to add a reference]

Annoyingly, the error message does not give a reason why.

[How to use a class from one C# project with another C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554658/how-to-use-a-class-from-one-c-sharp-project-with-another-c-sharp-project)

[Common controls for UWP and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754399/common-controls-for-uwp-and-wpf)

[Reference a class library from UWP and ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028887/reference-a-class-library-from-uwp-and-asp-net-5) (solution here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP is not compatible with .NET Core or .NET 6.

If you want to share code between a WPF app and a UWP app, your shared project should target .NET Standard 2.0.

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information about .NET Standard and the supported .NET implementations for each version.

Comment: Furthermore, an error message may appear saying that the Class Library cannot be referenced if the .NET Standard version is too advanced for the UWP Windows minimum targeted build. A simple downgrade in the Class Library properties > Application > Target framework solves this.

Comment: This looks to me like it should be the solution, but there are using statement referencing issues. Working that out.

Comment: Which  .NET Standard you can target depends on which version of the UWP you are targeting. As stated in the docs I linked to, .NET Standard 2.0 is compatible with UWP 10.0.16299.

Comment: There were some issues with VS not recognizing the reference to the common class, had to remove the reference, build, restart VS before it worked.

Comment: This entire setup is complete and utter twaddle